# Elasticsearch - update on key not id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents indexed in elasticsearch that I need to update.

The problem is that I don't know the elasticsearch id for the documents at update time. I have a unique key (say email address) that identifies each document - but the update API wants the elasticsearch id.

Do I need to query for each document first and get the elasticsearch id before doing the update? Sounds horribly inefficient. The updates are in batches of 100,000 in a 20,000,000 document index.

Answer (score 0):

For ***elasticsearch***, there is **no update by query mechanism**:

[Updating a field in all records in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946663/updating-a-field-in-all-records-in-elasticsearch).

And you can use `_bulk` api to efficiently update multi documents.