# Updating indexed documents in Elasticsearch based some criteria without using id

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have data indexed in Elasticsearch and want to update the documents having 'EMP_DEPT' as 'Software". So to do this is there any way to update matching documents without using the id of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Updating a field in all records in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946663/updating-a-field-in-all-records-in-elasticsearch)

Use the following plugin: https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/